# How do i take a string of letters (user input) and separate all duplicate characters with X's?

Tags: java, encryption, arraylist, substring

```
    System.out.print("Enter the message to encrypt: ");
    message = s.next().toString();  // this message is inserted

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    int index = 0;
    while (index < message.length())
    {
     strings.add(message.substring(index, Math.min(index + 2, 
     message.length())));   
              // separates the list by two's. i.e. [ST, EV, EN] for "Steven"
        index += 2;
    }
    System.out.println(strings);  // prints out list
    break;  // end of case

    /*
```

What I want to do with this code is separate duplicate characters by X's so that, for instance, if the name "William" was inserted, it would insert [WI, LX, LI, AM]. Also, if there is an odd number of letters (i.e. BOB), you would fill in the last number with an "X" to make it a pair: [BO, BX]

I have searched stack overflow consistently and cannot find an answer so any advice is greatly appreciated!
        */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create the string with replaced "X".
Then put that in the loop

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    String message = "";
    System.out.print("Enter the message to encrypt: ");
    input = s.next();  // this message is inserted

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
        if(i>0 && input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i-1)){
                stringBuilder.append("X");
                stringBuilder.append(input.charAt(i));

        }else{
            stringBuilder.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    if ( (stringBuilder.length() & 1) != 0 ) {
        stringBuilder.append("X");
    }
    message = stringBuilder.toString();
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    int index = 0;
    while (index < message.length())
    {
        strings.add(message.substring(index, Math.min(index + 2,
                message.length())));
        // separates the list by two's. i.e. [ST, EV, EN] for "Steven"
        index += 2;
    }
    System.out.println(strings); // prints out list
```

Comment: Perfect. One issue that I forgot to mention: how can I make certain that (given an odd number of letters), the final character will be paired with an X? For example "Jon" should be [JO, NX]

Comment: Check the edited answer. check string length is odd after processing and add one

Comment: Thank you!! Totally functional now. Respect, my friend.

Comment: Yes. I'm new to Stack Overflow. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Here the condition in the while loop should be

```
while (index+2 < message.length())
```

or else it might lead to index out of bound exception.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Any ideas on how to separate the duplicate characters with "X" 's ?

Comment: Extract the characters 2 at a stretch, compare them and replace the last one. If it has only one then replace the last position with x. Try to code it, if you are stuck let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply checking that if the substring is made of same characters then you can take the first character and concatenate it with 'X' and add it to the list and increase the index by 1. Else just add the substring in the list and increase the index by 2. Below is my modified while loop:

```
while (index < message.length())
        {
         //strings.add(message.substring(index, Math.min(index + 2, message.length()))); 

         String str = message.substring(index, Math.min(index + 2, 
                 message.length()));

                  // separates the list by two's. i.e. [ST, EV, EN] for "Steven"
         if(str.length() == 1 || str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1)) {
             strings.add(str.charAt(0) + "X");
             index += 1;
         }
         else{
             strings.add(str);
             index += 2;
         }

        }
```